# android vs iOS which choose

Tags: android, programming-languages, ios

I'm a Java developer and I want to start developing mobile applications.
The question is, which android or iOS seems to be better?
What can you tell me about the learning curve of each one?

I also want to know about the market or the profits of each alternative.

Comment: Check this one : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/ios-or-android-confused-what-to-start.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no *better*, just diferent.

I think this is greatly a matter of personal opinion, I develop on both platforms and think Android is a lot better, but have many coworkers that swear by iOS.

I jumped from Java to Android to iOS, being unfamiliar with Objective-C, i have to say the iOS learning curve for iOS is quite steep at first, the syntax for Objective-C is quite diferent from most languages, it doesnt feel like java, C, C++ or even Haskell, that said, once you get your head around it, its ok.

What market is better is something you have to ask someone with great future vision, Android seems to be growing like crazy, and I would bet on it, but you cant deny the Apple iOS fanbase is huge, and lots and lots of people wont be leaving iOS for a long time.

Apple seems to be the first to have ideas for a long time, even though they dont make the best products, they make them first, this gives them a huge advantage over competition.

So, if it were me, I would develop for Android, but I cant really tell you why, as I stated before, its really a matter of personal opinion. Decide for your self, take a look at some market stats for both the AppStore and Android Market, read their policies, and look through some tutorials for both platforms, after that you should be able to take a mildly educated guess at which to choose.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Java on iOS so I would say Android :)
The learning curve depend if you already have done some mobile development.

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty big question. One thing I can say is, Android apps are written in Java, so you've already got a head start there.

Answer (score 2):

The Objective C versus Java angle has been nicely covered with the other answers. The preferences here largely being subjective.

On the market/profit side, it kind of depends on what you're trying to do. Android is heavily skewed towards free or advertising supported apps. One factor in this is down to the fact that you actually *can't* buy apps in many of the countries that Android handsets are available in.

This means that if your business model requires people to purchase software, iOS is currently way ahead of anything else. For free software it's less clear. iOS users already download lots of apps. Android appears to be growing more quickly. Probably neither are bad choices.

This, of course, only factors in Android and iOS. BlackBerry has higher average selling prices for apps than iOS but probably fewer willing customers. It's also, I believe, Java based. Windows Phone 7 could be interesting, especially for enterprise developers already familiar with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Well for you, Android would have the easier learning curve since the Android SDK is all Java.  For iOS you'll have to learn Objective-C which is significantly different from Java.

As for which is "better", that's entirely subjective.  And as far as what the market is like, there's plenty of material on that out there.

Answer (score 1):

i would go for android , the market is growing rapidly and there are many area for improvements plus it uses a language we all know & familiar with , Java

Comment: +1: Cool answer, but saying that everybody knows Java is a strong statement

Comment: sorry not everybody , but its the most used programming language as Tiobe suggests

Answer (score 0):

Objective C relate to Cocoa like Java to Android.

Android is like a Framwork for Java.